# Use of prepositions 'in' and 'on'

Tags: prepositions

> Luis arrived in the United States in June 2002.
>   He started school on August 29th.

Why June is used with 'in' and August is used with 'on'?

Answer (score 0):

'in' is used where the date is not specific... According to the sentence, Luis might have arrived on any date in June but he joined school 'on' a specific date i.e. 29th August. For specific time 'at' is used.
All these are prepositions.